# Copy content of parent directory to sub directory

Tags: bash, shell

I need to copy the content of the parent directory to the newly created sub-directory.

Initially, the structure is like this:

```
Parent
    abc.txt
    work_dir/
        script.sh
```

Expected Output:

```
Parent
    abc.txt
    work_dir/
        script.sh
    sub_dir/
        abc.txt
        work_dir/
            script.sh
```

Now I am in the work_dir, and I am executing `script.sh`. The content of this file is below:

```
/bin/sh
mkdir ../sub_dir
shopt -s extglob
cp -r ../!(sub_dir) ../sub_dir/
```

I get the following error: syntax error near unexpected token `('.  Error: exit status 2

If I change it to this `cp -r '../!(sub_dir)' ../sub_dir/`, I get `cp: ../!(sub_dir): No such file or directory`

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: `bash != sh` The `!( ... )` is an extglob feature from the `bash` shell.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to solve this?

Comment: Sure, change `sh` to `bash` from the shebang.

Comment: when I change it to `bash` and then I run `mkdir ../sub_dir; shopt -s extglob; pwd; cp -r ../!(sub_dir) ../sub_dir/ ` I get `bash: !: event not found`

Comment: That is history expansion, It only happens from interactive shell. Disable it via `set +H`

Comment: It seems its not working for me :(

Comment: The goal is to copy the parent folder content to the child folder. Is there any other way?

Comment: Just run  `cp -r !("my sub dir") "my sub dir"` in the parent directory. Note that where the script lives has nothing to do with where it executes.

Comment: `cp -r ../!(sub_dir) ../sub_dir/` in a script works here with bash 5.0.3 and `extglob` enabled.

Comment: Is the first line of your script really, literally `/bin/sh`? This would just start a new interactive subshell.

Comment: @Jetchisel : You are right, but in this case, the OP would see an error message saying that `shopt ` is not found.

Comment: You also did not say how you invoked your script. This makes it difficult to judge what's really going on.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` solved the issue. See the updated code:

```
/bin/sh
mkdir ../sub_dir
rsync -a --exclude=../sub_dir ../ ../sub_dir/
```